# Apache Avoid "Too Many Requests"

Tags: php, apache

I'm currently running a server which sometimes is asked for a lot of photos (about 100) and I'm getting Too Many Requests problem. I've tried to search what option I have to change to avoid this but with no success. How can it be solved?

Comment: try posting here https://serverfault.com/

Comment: please add your code here

Comment: you should use pagination if data that will solve your problem

Comment: Which code? PHP? The errors? Apache config? I'm confused :\

Comment: Ask over at server fault. You'll need to optimize your Apache config. You may also want to try looking into a CDN, if the images are what's slowing things down.

Comment: That is more of an apache config question.  You need to look into your MPM parameters to increase the number of workers.  100 photos is not that much (well unless the page is visited tons of times!).  But since MPM can be diffrent from one install of apache to the next, it's hard to help without the full config.

Comment: Which config file? SOrry for asking, I'm still new at this.